# The application requesting authentication tokens is either disabled or incorrectly configured

Tags: c#, authentication, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app

I was trying for microsoft login in my windows 10 UWP app.

```
var authenticator = new Windows.Security.Authentication.OnlineId.OnlineIdAuthenticator();
var serviceTicketRequest = new Windows.Security.Authentication.OnlineId.OnlineIdServiceTicketRequest("wl.basic", "DELEGATION");

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Signing in...");

var authResult = await authenticator.AuthenticateUserAsync(serviceTicketRequest);
```

this was the code I was trying. I got exception at `authenticator.AuthenticateUserAsync` The exception was

> Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> Additional information: The application requesting authentication tokens is either disabled or incorrectly configured. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80860003)
>   Anyone have Idea why this happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The exception here is that your app didn't associate with the Windows Store.

To associate your app with the Windows Store, open your app's project file in Visual Studio:

1. From the **Store** menu, select **Associate App with the Store...**
   [image]
2. Click **Sign in** to sign into your Windows Store developer account using your Microsoft account credentials. If you don't have a Windows Store developer account, go to your [**Windows Store Dashboard**](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=233762) to create one, and then restart this procedure.
3. Select the app from the list with which you want to associate your app in Visual Studio. If the app is not listed, click **Reserve name** to add it to your Windows Store developer account.
4. Click **Next** to review the info that the wizard will add to your app.
5. If the info looks correct, click **Associate** and the wizard will update your app's package manifest.

After associating, you can avoid this exception and authenticate user with Microsoft Account.

Comment: Why is this not documented anywhere? Or did I miss something?

Comment: I believe this is documented in step #4 here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/get-started-with-creators/develop-creators-title-with-visual-studio

Comment: Even after doing this, I still can't log-in with MSAs. I made the mistake of removing the Live SDK application in the Application Registration Portal, and unable to create a new entry with a Windows Store association for my app. I have a Converged application in the Application Registration Portal, but it doesn't seem to work.